# Reboot only shuts down and doesn't actually boot again

Tags: 12.04, boot, server, power-management, reboot

I'm running a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 Server on an abmx rack mount server. When I attempt to reboot with `sudo shutdown -r now`, the machine just shuts down and doesn't come back up without me manually pressing the power button.

The output of `last -x`,

```
runlevel (to lvl 2)   3.2.0-29-generic Wed Oct 31 14:32 - 14:37  (00:05)                                                                                                               
reboot   system boot  3.2.0-29-generic Wed Oct 31 14:32 - 14:37  (00:05)                                                                                                               
shutdown system down  3.2.0-29-generic Wed Oct 31 14:30 - 14:32  (00:02)                                                                                                               
runlevel (to lvl 6)   3.2.0-29-generic Wed Oct 31 14:30 - 14:30  (00:00)
```

This appears to show that the system rebooted, but it went dark (no power lights, BIOS, etc) and I had to go press the power button in order to make it boot back up. The machine does have some sort of Intel Boot Agent that usually appears before the BIOS, I'm wondering if it could be causing this. I'm not sure what information is useful for debugging this, but I put the output of `lshw` in http://pastebin.com/mBy72kTQ

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problems was related to Intel AMT and the "mei" driver ([solution found here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2024096) ).

Putting this into /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf fixes the reboot issue,

```
blacklist mei
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an asus server mainboard and suse 42.1 leap. I had to put two lines into /etc/modprobe.d/50blacklist.conf

blacklist mei

blacklist mei_me

hth, Matthias

Comment: Is this an answer ? Please see if you can put out an answer!