# sudo reboot shuts down instead of rebooting on a X10SLM-F

Tags: server, shutdown

I have a server with the motherboard X10SLM-F (Supermicro). I successfully installed Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS on it. The problem I have is that, when I give the command: `sudo reboot`, the server doesn't reboot it shuts off the server.

The shutdown command works without any issues, but not the reboot command. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo shutdown -r now`?

Comment: @Donarsson: The OP wants to reboot, not shutdown. `shutdown` works without issues.

Comment: @Jobin I know. the `-r` means reboot. On most machines, `reboot` is just a symlink to the above command anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Try using command

> sudo shutdown -r 0

That should  reboot. **sudo** is for administrator privileges, **shutdown** is like shutdown menu, **-r** stands for reboot and **0** means in 0 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Further research pointed me to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2024096 and [Reboot only shuts down and doesn't actually boot again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210249/reboot-only-shuts-down-and-doesnt-actually-boot-again).

However, in addition to blacklisting the mei driver, I had to blacklist mei_me to keep that driver from pulling it in.

This was done by editing /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and adding the following

```
blacklist mei
blacklist mei_me
```