# problems with reboot after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, reboot

when Ubuntu reboots itself after an update ( unattended-upgrades) or when I send the reboot command manually, sometimes it happens that instead of rebooting, the server shuts down.
How can I solve the problem ?

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/443372/1004020 . Otherwise, look into enabling `kexec` instead