# restart does not work

Tags: restart

I click on restart on the top menu, but the system only shut down. I have to manually to push power button to restart the machine.

Is it normal behaviour for Ubuntu or I need to check my configuration?

Your help and information is great appreciated,

Regards,

Inung

Comment: what happens when you run `sudo reboot`?

Comment: sudo reboot works, Regards, Inung

Comment: Check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/210249/reboot-only-shuts-down-and-doesnt-actually-boot-again